# How to skip a failed api lookup and pass null parameters instead?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, api, promises

If the "Title" parameter isn't passed via the url, then my initial api call fails, but even failure, I need it continue to the my item save routine.

Unfortunately, an error is thrown on `siteIdFromParameter = data.d.results[0].Id` (because there isn't a parameter to execute the query against).  In that situation, how would I just skip that "failure" and then pass null values for SiteUrl and SiteID?

```
function getUrlParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
    var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
        urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
    }
    return urlparameter;
}

function addFeatureSuggestion() {

   var siteUrlFromParameter = getUrlParam('Title', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    $.ajax({
     url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName2 + "')/items?$filter=SitePath eq '/sites/" + siteUrlFromParameter + "'",

        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        async: false,
        headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
           "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
    }).then(function (data) {
        siteIdFromParameter = data.d.results[0].Id

        item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.FeatureSuggestionsListItem" },
        "SiteURL": siteUrlFromParameter,
        "SiteId": siteIdFromParameter,
        "Title": $('#inputTitle').val(),
        "Suggestion": $('#inputSuggestion').val()
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: your `.then(` still executes right?  It just fails on `data.d.results[0].Id`?

Comment: Yes.. it still executes, but fails  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case the SiteUrl is nonexistent or invalid, your `then` promise resolution should still fire, but the `data` parameter passed to it will likely either contain an error object, or at least not contain the siteID your were trying to retrieve.  Inside your `then`, create your `item` without the `Site` parameters, then inspect each sub-level of the returned data (for [truth-iness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)) to determine whether you got good results, and only add in the `Site` values if you have a good result set:

```
function addFeatureSuggestion() {
    var siteUrlFromParameter = getUrlParam('Title', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    $.ajax({
     url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName2 + "')/items?$filter=SitePath eq '/sites/" + siteUrlFromParameter + "'",


        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        async: false,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
    }).then(function (data) {
        item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.FeatureSuggestionsListItem" },
            "Title": $('#inputTitle').val(),
            "Suggestion": $('#inputSuggestion').val()
        };

        if (data && data.d && data.d.results && data.d.results.length && data.d.results[0].Id) {
            siteIdFromParameter = data.d.results[0].Id

            item.SiteURL = siteUrlFromParameter;
            item.SiteId = siteIdFromParameter;
        }

        // do something with `item` here
    });
}
```